# Why the progressBar in form1 never being update?

Tags: c#, winforms

it does download and process the files. but it's not updating the progressBar.

a bit long code but it's all connected.  i tried to minimal compact it.

in form1 top

```
public enum RadarState
{
    Waiting,
    Initializing,
    Downloading,
    DownloadCompleted,
    ImageProcessing,
    ImageProcessed,
}

private readonly ProgressBar _downloadProgress;
private DateTime _nextDownloadTime = DateTime.Now;
private string folderToSaveImage;
private Radar _radar;
private int successfulDownloadsCount = 0;
private Timer _downloadTimer;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _downloadProgress = new ProgressBar
    {
        Location = lblNextTimeDownload.Location,
        Size = lblNextTimeDownload.Size,
        Dock = DockStyle.Top,
        Value = 0,
    };
    lblImagesCounter.Text = "Images Counter: 0";

    _downloadTimer = new Timer();
    _downloadTimer.Tick += _downloadTimer_Tick;

    // Subscribe event in the constructor
    _radar = new Radar(folderToSaveImage);
    _radar.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        switch (args.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(_radar.State):
                // Update the title bar
                BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    if (_radar.State == RadarState.ImageProcessed)
                    {
                        successfulDownloadsCount++;  // Increment the counter
                        var filesToProcess = Directory.GetFiles(folderToSaveImage, "*.png").Count(filePath => !filePath.Contains("_Processed"));
                        var filesProcessedAlready = successfulDownloadsCount - filesToProcess;
                        lblImagesCounter.Text = $"Images Count: {filesProcessedAlready}";  // Update the label
                    }
                    else if (_radar.State == RadarState.ImageProcessing)
                    {
                        Text = "Radar - ImagesProcessing";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Text = $"Radar - {_radar.State}";
                    }
                });
                break;
            case nameof(_radar.Progress):
                // Update the progress bar
                if (!Disposing) BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    _downloadProgress.Value = _radar.Progress;
                });
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

this is the code for adding the progressBar control:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    Controls.Add(_downloadProgress);
}
```

I used a breakpoint but it's never reaching the code:

```
_downloadProgress.Value = _radar.Progress;
```

the class that updates the progress:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static Weather_Images.Form1;

namespace Weather_Images
{
    public class Radar : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Radar(string inputFolder)
        {
            Folder = inputFolder;
        }

        public string Folder { get; }
        public string DefaultLink { get; } = "https://ims.gov.il/sites/default/files/ims_data/map_images/IMSRadar4GIS/IMSRadar4GIS_";
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public RadarState State
        {
            get => _state;
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_state, value))
                {
                    _state = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        RadarState _state = default;
        public int Progress
        {
            get => _progress;
            set
            {
                if (!Equals(_progress, value))
                {
                    _progress = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        int _progress = default;

        int successfulDownloadsCount = 0;

        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public async Task ExececuteAsync()
        {
            State = RadarState.Initializing;
            PrepareLinks();
            await DownloadImagesAsync();
            await ProcessDownloadedImagesAsync();
            State = RadarState.Waiting;
        }
        public List<string> Links { get; } = new List<string>();
        public Dictionary<string, string> LinksAndFileNames { get; } = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public void PrepareLinks()
        {
            LinksAndFileNames.Clear();
            Links.Clear();

            GenerateRadarLinks();

            // Exclude links for files that already exist in the folder
            var downloadedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.png")
                            .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
                            .Where(fileName => fileName.EndsWith("_Processed"))
                            .ToList();
        }

        private void GenerateRadarLinks()
        {
            DateTime current = RoundDown(DateTime.Now, 1);

            if (!Directory.Exists(Folder + "\\Dates"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Folder + "\\Dates");
            }

            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(Folder + "\\Dates\\" + "dates.txt"))
            using (StreamWriter ww = new StreamWriter(Folder + "\\Dates\\" + "datesTime.txt"))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
                {
                    var date = current.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
                    ww.WriteLine(current.ToString());
                    w.WriteLine(date);
                    var link = DefaultLink + date + "_0.png";
                    Links.Add(link);
                    LinksAndFileNames.Add(link, current.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm"));
                    current = current.AddMinutes(-1);
                }
            }
        }
        private DateTime RoundDown(DateTime dt, int NearestMinuteInterval) =>
            new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute / NearestMinuteInterval * NearestMinuteInterval, 0);

        private async Task DownloadImagesAsync()
        {
            Progress = 0;
            int totalFiles = Links.Count(link => !link.Contains("_Processed"));
            int completedFiles = 0;

            if (totalFiles > 0)
            {
                // Signal that the actual download has started
                State = RadarState.Downloading;

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    foreach (var link in Links.Where(link => !link.Contains("_Processed")))
                    {
                        var fileName = LinksAndFileNames[link];
                        var filePath = Path.Combine(Folder, fileName + ".png");

                        try
                        {
                            // Download the file if it doesn't exist
                            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                            {
                                byte[] fileData = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(link);
                                File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileData);

                                // Increment the progress based on the number of files downloaded
                                completedFiles++;
                                Progress = (int)((double)completedFiles / totalFiles * 100);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            // Handle download errors if necessary
                            Console.WriteLine($"Error downloading file: {ex.Message}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Notify completion
            State = RadarState.DownloadCompleted;
            Progress = 100;
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }

        private async Task ProcessDownloadedImagesAsync()
        {
            Progress = 0;
            var filesToProcess = Directory.GetFiles(Folder, "*.png").Where(filePath => !filePath.Contains("_Processed"));

            if (filesToProcess.Any())
            {
                int totalFiles = filesToProcess.Count();
                int completedFiles = 0;

                foreach (var filePath in filesToProcess)
                {
                    State = RadarState.ImageProcessing;

                    // Use Task.Run to offload synchronous work to a background thread
                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        // Process the downloaded image
                        RadarImagesConvertor convertor = new RadarImagesConvertor(filePath, Folder);
                    });

                    // Signal that the image has been processed
                    State = RadarState.ImageProcessed;

                    // Update the progress
                    completedFiles++;
                    Progress = (int)((double)completedFiles / totalFiles * 100);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i used a breakpoint inside the two methods on the lines:

```
Progress = (int)((double)completedFiles / totalFiles * 100);
```

and using a breakpoint it's reaching these lines.  but it's never reaching to the form1 and never updating the progressBar.

this is the button click event in form1 that execute the code in the class Radar.

```
private async void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (FolderBrowserDialog folderDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
    {
        // Set the initial folder (optional)
        folderDialog.SelectedPath = @"C:\";

        // Show the dialog and capture the result
        DialogResult result = folderDialog.ShowDialog();

        // Check if the user selected a folder
        if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(folderDialog.SelectedPath))
        {
            lblNextTimeDownload.Visible = false;
            btnDownload.Enabled = false;

            // Use the selected folder path
            string selectedFolder = folderDialog.SelectedPath;
            folderToSaveImage = selectedFolder;
            _radar = new Radar(folderToSaveImage);
            await _radar.ExececuteAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to post the line of code that adds the ProgressBar (`_downloadProgress`) to the `Controls` collection? -- You're creating a `Radar` object in the Constructor of the Form, and you're adding an event handler to its `PropertyChanged` event. In the `btnDownload` handler, you're creating a new instance of the `Radar` class, assigning it to the same Field... -- You probably misinterpreted the use of `BeginInvoke()`

Comment: @Jimi right I remember now that i have a problem with the Radar class instance in form1 so that's why the confusion and why i created two instances.  because the radar instance should get a folder where the files will be downloaded to.  and it should be in the btnDownload_Click event because this is where I select and set the download folder.  but i don't want to register to the event _radar.PropertyChanged in the button click event.  so i register it once in the constructor but then the folderToSaveImage is still null.

Comment: @Jimi because i didn't want to make instance of the radar class in the button click event by mistake i created two instances in both places and this is where the confusion is.  what should i do then to solve it ?

Comment: Modify your Radar class, so that you can change its `Folder` property without recreating the class (the `ExececuteAsync()` doesn't even need a change, from what I'm seeing here) -- If you overwrite the Field that holds the reference to the Radar class, when you have already added an event handler, you lose the event subscription -- Note that your class is not thread-safe, or *concurrent-safe*. Make sure that the button is not clicked twice by mistake -- You should (really) move the call to `await _radar.ExececuteAsync();` outside the `using` block -- The use of `BeginInvoke()` is wrong